# Ler vários arquivos de texto usando o System.IO e o Visual C# .NET e escrevendo nestes arquivos

Tags: c#, txt

Meu problema é o seguinte. Tenho vários arquivos .txt em um diretorio do pc. Esses arquivos tem informacoes em cada linha e possuem linhas em branco.

O que eu precisaria fazer é ler todos os arquivos do diretorio, abrir um a um, ler as informacoes de cada, e adicionar um index numérico em cada, seguido de um ponto e vírgula e apagando as linhas em branco ou com espaço.

Voilà, consegui parcialmente.

Meu programa le o diretorio, lista os arquivos, abre e lê as informacoes neles, mas quando vai gravar as informacoes, ele replica as informacoes do primeiro arquivo no segundo.

Ex.: Se num arquivo tenho a disposicao

```
joao
legal
```

o resultado no primeiro arquivo é

```
0;joao
1;legal
```

no segundo arquivo tenho as informacoes:

```
marcelo
medeiros
```

mas, depois de executar o programa, o resultado no segundo arquivo é:

```
0;joao
1;legal
2;marcelo
3;medeiros
```

Logo, se houverem varios e varios arquivos, voces imaginam como ficaria o arquivo final.

Alguém consegue me auxiliar em encontrar onde está o erro no meu programa?

Segue o código:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<string> lines = new List<string>();

    string path3;
    int counter = 0;


    path3 = @"C:\Users\msant\Desktop\New folder\";

    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path3);

    foreach (var file in files)
    {

        if (File.Exists(file))
        {
            try
            {
                //ABRE E LÊ O ARQUIVO TXT

                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file))
                {
                    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                    {

                        string line = reader.ReadLine();

                        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
                        {
                            var lineOutput = counter++ + ";";
                            lines.Add(lineOutput + line);
                        }

                    }
                    reader.Close();
                    reader.Dispose();
                }

                foreach (var line in lines)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine(line);
                }


                //ESCREVE NOS ARQUIVOS TXT

                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(file))
                {
                    foreach (var item in lines)
                    {
                        writer.WriteLine(item);
                    }

                    writer.Close();
                }


            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }

        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ALERTA: O ARQUIVO LOCALIZADO EM <-- " + path3+ " --> NAO EXISTE.");
        }


        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Então, primeiramente você não precisaria de declarar o `Dispose()` dentro do seu bloco `using`pois a utilização de `using` permite que as classes que implementem *IDisposable* sejam usadas de forma a garantir a execução do método `Dispose()` no fim da sua utilização, mesmo que lance uma exceção.

Ele está escrevendo tudo novamente no segundo arquivo pois sua variável *Lines* está fora do seu `for` fazendo com que a mesma não seja inicializada novamente a cada repetição por arquivo, assim quando escrever o arquivo a mesma está com os valores anteriores.

Você pode jogar a inicialização dela para dentro do for fazendo com que toda repetição ela seja limpa novamente:

```js
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string path3;
        int counter = 0;


        path3 = @"C:\Users\msant\Desktop\New folder\";

        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path3);

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            List<string> lines = new List<string>();

            if (File.Exists(file))
            {
                try
                {
                    //ABRE E LÊ O ARQUIVO TXT

                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file))
                    {
                        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                        {

                            string line = reader.ReadLine();

                            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
                            {
                                var lineOutput = counter++ + ";";
                                lines.Add(lineOutput + line);
                            }

                        }
                        reader.Close();
                    }

                    foreach (var line in lines)
                    {

                        Console.WriteLine(line);
                    }


                    //ESCREVE NOS ARQUIVOS TXT

                    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(file))
                    {
                        foreach (var item in lines)
                        {
                            writer.WriteLine(item);
                        }

                        writer.Close();
                    }


                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }
            }

            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ALERTA: O ARQUIVO LOCALIZADO EM <-- " + path3+ " --> NAO EXISTE.");
            }


            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta! ;)

Comment: Apenas um adendo no código, se eu simplesmente transferir o lines para dentro do for, ele pega apenas o primeiro arquivo. Mudei assim: antes do if(File.Exists) , declarei novamente  a variavel lines: lines = new List<string>(); e o contador novamente a 0 - counter = 0; - caso contrario ele seguira o index e vai numerar em sequencia todos os arquivos. Valeu Victor!!

Answer (score 2):

Como o Victor falou, o problema é que não está limpando a lista.

Fora isso, uma outra opção de código:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string path = @"D:\Teste\";

    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path,"*.txt", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
    List<string> valores = new List<string>();
    foreach (string file in files)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Processando arquivo {file}");
        string[] linhas = File.ReadAllLines(file);
        foreach (string linha in linhas)
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(linha))
                valores.Add(linha);


        using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(file, false, Encoding.Default))
        {
            for (int i =0; i< valores.Count; i++)
            {
                tw.WriteLine($"{i};{valores[i]}");
            }
        }

        valores.Clear();

    }

    Console.ReadKey();

}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela opcao! Muito elegante ;)